# Is Shiva praised within the Valmiki-Ramayan?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, bhakti, reference-request

Are there any verses within the Valmiki-Ramayana that praise Shiva? If so could you please refer to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't quite praise him long-windedly, but there are positive notions of Shiva. Here are two such lines:

> [[7.61]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424835.html)
> “Thus spoke Madhu, and **the Lord of all beings, Shiva, that great God**, answered him.

> [[7.87]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424861.html)
> The king was sorely disappointed by this reply of **the magnanimous Shiva**.